# Symfony Form Type from 2.5.9 no longer recognized, although still using 2.5.9

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I am using Symfony 2.5.9 and recently ran `composer update`. On a page with a form I now get:

> InvalidArgumentException: Could not load type "Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType" (0)

Before the update, that page was rendering fine. The form is

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;

class TaskType extends AbstractType {

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('name')
                ->add('info', 'text', array());
    }

  public function getName() {
        return 'myapp_mybundle_tasktype';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MyApp\MyBundle\Entity\Task'
        ));
    }

}
```

Reading some other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33164001), it appears that this is because in Symfony 3 the above method of creating the form element type is no longer used. But I need to use 2.5.9 for now.

Even when I copy and paste the composer.json from the master branch (i.e. unaffected and working) and run `composer update`, I get the same error.

I've also tried removing everything from the vendor folder and refreshing both caches, and re-running `composer update` but the same error appears on page load. How can this be? Rather than using a workaround, what reason is there for this requirement change? I still see Symfony 2.5.9 in the dev toolbar.

The composer file:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "": "src/"
        },
        "classmap": ["vendor/MediovskiTechnology/php-crontab-manager/src/"]
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.5.9",
        "symfony/console": "2.5.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "1.1.*@dev",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.7",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.6.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "3.0.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "3.0.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.5.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.4.*",
        "kriswallsmith/assetic": "~1.1",
        "phpoffice/phpexcel": "1.8.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/data-fixtures": "1.0.*@dev",
        "kriswallsmith/buzz": "dev-master",
        "mlpz/postmark-bundle": "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "*",
        "monolog/monolog": "1.10.0",
        "querypath/querypath": "dev-master",
        "MediovskiTechnology/php-crontab-manager": "0.9.3",
        "mtdowling/cron-expression": "1.1.0",
        "drak/native-session": "*",
        "egulias/email-validator": "~1.2",
        "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "5.2.1",
        "twilio/sdk": "^5.4",
        "hybridauth/hybridauth": "2.6.0",
        "symfony/doctrine-bridge": "~2.7"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by changing

```
"doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
```

to

```
"doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.3.0",
```